# Error Displayed with JToolbar DeleteList Static Function

Tags: php, joomla, components, jtoolbar

I am building a Joomla 2.5 component and have a bit of trouble getting the `Delete` button to function properly.  Here is a sample code from the `view.html.php` file:

```
if ($canDo->get('core.delete'))
    {
        JToolBarHelper::deleteList('You Really Wanna Delete that', mycomponentname.delete, 'JTOOLBAR_DELETE');
```

When I select an item from a dropdown list and click to delete I get the following pop-up:

`You Really Wanna Delete that`

The problem with this is when I click the option to verify the deletion from the pop-up I am redirected to a 500 error message and the item is not deleted.

Now when I review the Joomla documentation here:

`http://docs.joomla.org/JToolBarHelper`

I see that `JToolBarHelper` is defined in `administrator/includes/toolbar.php`.  So I went for a visit over to review the `deleteList` info there.  I see the following code:

```
public static function deleteList($msg = '', $task = 'remove', $alt = 'JTOOLBAR_DELETE')
{
    $bar = JToolBar::getInstance('toolbar');
    // Add a delete button.
    if ($msg) {
        $bar->appendButton('Confirm', $msg, 'delete', $alt, $task, true);
    } else {
        $bar->appendButton('Standard', 'delete', $alt, $task, true);
    }
 }
```

So I have attempted to adjust my script by changing the second parameter `$task = 'remove'` to read as `remove` rather than `mycomponentname.delete` as follows:

`JToolBarHelper::deleteList('You Really Wanna Delete that', 'remove', 'JTOOLBAR_DELETE');`

This will eliminate the 500 error, but the item is not removed.  What am I missing here?  My guess is that it has something to do with improperly configuring the `mycomponentname.delete` function.

---

PS- I should add that the 500 error states:

`Layout default not found`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one problem you have. You don't need to put the component name on to the button task. You need to put controller name instead of component name.

```
if ($canDo->get('core.delete'))
{
    JToolBarHelper::deleteList('You Really Wanna Delete that', 'controllerName.delete', 'JTOOLBAR_DELETE');
}
```

**For example :**

```
JToolBarHelper::deleteList('delete', 'hellos.delete','JTOOLBAR_DELETE');
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to get it working.  I had a few more errors in there as well, but now it is good to go.